# Replacing indices in an array with 1 doesn't work

Tags: arrays, r, for-loop, matrix, edge-detection

I'm trying to implement an edge detection function for some PNG images in R. My function runs fine - taking an array and making each numeric value the standard deviation of values near it. Then, I find the indices of values in the top 1% of standard deviations in the photo (the edges).

However, I'm running into an odd issue when trying to replace these indices with "1". The code that I've written is below:

```
vg_new <- vg
for (i in nrow(outlier_indices)){
  row <- outlier_indices[i,1] ; column <- outlier_indices[i,2]
  vg_new[row, column, 1] <- 1
  vg_new[row, column, 2] <- 1
  vg_new[row, column, 3] <- 1
}
```

For some background, vg_new (and vg) are the pictures - they're each an array of 3 matrices, each 374x800. outlier_indices is my 64255x2 matrix of indices, the first column being the row index and the second column being the column index.

Thus, I'm trying to replace the correct indices in each color channel (each separate matrix in vg_new) with "1". However, when I run this loop nothing is actually changing. However, when I run something like:

```
vg_new[50, 1, 1] <- 1
```

the index changes no problem. I've checked to make sure all indices in "outlier_indices" exist in "vg_new" and they all do. Any ideas as to what's going on here? Am I missing something obvious?

Here's a full example:

```
vg <- array(0, c(374, 800, 3))
outlier_indices <- matrix(c(1:50), c(1:50), nrow = 50, ncol = 2)
for (i in nrow(outlier_indices)){
  row <- outlier_indices[i,1] ; column <- outlier_indices[i,2]
  vg[row, column, 1] <- 1
  vg[row, column, 2] <- 2
  vg[row, column, 3] <- 3
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Note that if `vg_new` is a local variable then you would not expect any changes to the array to persist after the function returns. Perhaps you are modifying a copy of an array and then discarding the changes

Comment: It seems that you'll need `1:nrow(outlier_indices)` as your sequence

Comment: @alexis_laz I see now - can't believe I didn't catch this earlier. Thank you very much!